# Objects were released still they gave their values . ARC were Not mark (means Off)

Tags: objective-c, copy, release, retain

**Objects were released still they gave their values . ARC were Not mark (means Off)**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{   
     [super viewDidLoad];

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     //test of retain and copy

      NSString *s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"String1"];
      NSString *s2 = [s1 copy];

      [s1 release];
      [s1 release];
      [s2 release];

      if(s1!=nil)
      {
            NSLog(@"11111");
            NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
            [array release];

            NSLog(@"S1 - %@ \n S2 - %@ \n Array - %@",s1,s2,array);
       }
  }
```

===output===

2012-12-14 15:04:01.165 testMM[940:207] 11111
2012-12-14 15:04:01.168 testMM[940:207] S1 - String1 
 S2 - String1 
 Array - S1 - String1 
 S2 - String1 
 Array -

Answer (score 0):

First, accessing a deallocated object is **undefined behavior**. It may access what looks like the original object (if the memory it used hasn't been overwritten), or it may access another object (that happens to be allocated there later), or it may access random garbage (not an object at all), or it may crash or do other weird things. There is no way to tell whether an object is deallocated or not, unless you run with zombies turned on to catch calls to deallocated objects.

Not only that, there is also no guarantee of when an object will be deallocated even after you release all your retains on it. An object is deallocated when its retain count goes to 0. But even if you allocated and release an object, it is possible that some API could have retained and then autoreleased it. e.g. you allocate and then immediately release the array, but it is possible that in `initWithObjects:` it retains and autoreleases itself (it is never incorrect to retain and autorelease an object), though that is unlikely in an `init`.

Specifically in this case, for the strings, `@"String1"` is a literal string that exists in static memory and memory management operations on it like `retain` and `release` don't do anything. `NSString`, when you create a new string based on a constant string, simply returns that constant string; and `copy` on a constant string also returns that constant string. So basically `s1` and `s2` both point to a string literal in static memory that lives forever. `release` on them have no effect. (But are still incorrect from a memory management rules point of view.)

`array` was allocated and released. What likely happened here (I am guessing here, due to the above reasons) is that the array is indeed deallocated, but that part of memory was not overwritten by the time you print it since it was such a short period of time. Again, this is undefined behavior.